# How to call method of activity in Fragment?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have the following listView:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //CheckBoxAdapter cb = new CheckBoxAdapter(this.getActivity(),R.layout.item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.products));
    //lv.setAdapter(cb);
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);

    ListView lv = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listProduct);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String type = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        MainActivity.AddSubscription(String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
                    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
```

But currently I cannot reference addSubscription which is nonstatic

```
MainActivity.AddSubscription(String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
```

I need to create a non static listener which can call addsubscription, is it possible with a listview? If not can I use another type of view?

Comment: remove MainActivity. , call directly AddSubscription(...) method

Comment: This is in a fragment

Answer (score 0):

Simply if your fragment is placed in MainActivity do this:

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).AddSubscription(String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
```

Comment: Doesn't work, first off the method addsubscription is inside mainactivity, second it gave me the error: "MainActivity is not an enclosing class"

Comment: This listview is in a fragment

Comment: Oh, if in fragment, did you tried to call `getActivity()`?

Comment: It appears like this gave me a NullPointerException

Comment: Try to replace `getActivity()` with `getContext()`

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `getActivity()` and cast it as this approach seems to fragile to me.

I typed this out of my head without an IDE so there might be typos.
Let the `Activity` implement an interface `SubscriptionHandler`

```
public interface SubscriptionHandler {
    public void addSubscription(String identifier);
}
```

Actitiy

```
public MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SubscriptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyFragment fragment = (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
        fragment.setSubscriptionHandler(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void addSubscription(String identifier){
   //logic
   }

}
```

and then use this in the Fragment

```
 public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable private SubscriptionHandler subscriptionHandler;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);

        ListView lv = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listProduct);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String type = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position)+" is selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    try {
                        if(subscriptionManager != null) {
                            subscriptionHandler.addSubscription(String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
                        }
                    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
           }
     );

     public void setSubscriptionHandler (SubscriptionHandler subscriptionHandler) {
        this.subscriptionHandler = subscriptionHandler;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ok thank you, do you know how to fetch the fragment? instanciating a fragmentmanager and calling findfragmentbyId only seems to return an object of type fragment, I need it to be of the same class type as mine.

Comment: Using the FragmentManager is the right approach, you just have to cast it in the same way as you do with Buttons and all the other views. Make sure to use the right FragmentManager. I edited the answer

Comment: It seems like this approach returns null , I hope I've added the id xml tag at the right place android:id="@+id/listFragment" this is under the framelayout

Comment: It depends on if you create the Fragment in the xml or create it programmatically. If you create it yourself `new MyFragment` and set it to the layout, then just call `setSubscriptionHandler` there. I am sorry I cannot be of more help. There are many ways to create Fragments and it is hard to help out more without the code

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in the listener:

```
YourFragmentName.this.((MainActivity)getActivity()).AddSubscription(String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)));
```